# Find elements by class name with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<div class="innerImageOuterWrapper">
  <div class="innerImageWrapper editlink" id="imageGridWrapper_15961315" ximgid="23232323" onclick="displayEditImageBox('IMSIMAGE:ASDASD', 233232, 'new')" style="background: transparent url(&quot;https://xsad.com/xsd.jpg;) center center / cover no-repeat;">
    <img src="https://xsad.com/xsd.jpg" class="thumbnail scaleimg" id="imageGridimage_15961315" style="display: none;" wfd-invisible="true">
  </div>
  <div class="innerImageWrapper editlink" id="imageGridWrapper_15961314" ximgid="15961314" onclick="displayEditImageBox('IMSIMAGE:ASDASD23', 15961314, 'new')" style="background: transparent url(&quot;https://xsad.com/xsd.jpg&quot;) center center / cover no-repeat;">
    <img src="https://xsad.com/xsdsd.jpg" class="thumbnail scaleimg" id="imageGridimage_15961314" style="display: none;" wfd-invisible="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to click on elements whose class is "innerImageWrapper editlink".

I use this code

```py
driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="innerImageWrapper editlink").click()
```

but it's not working.

```py
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                value='//*[@id="imageGridWrapper_15961314"').click()
```

it's working. but I dont want use xpath. I want use class name

Comment: Try: driver.find_element_by_id('imageGridWrapper_15961314').click()

Comment: I just want use class. because there are so much id. "15961314" "15961323" etc. It's all random and too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.CLASS_NAME` receives single value while here you trying to pass 2 values: `innerImageWrapper` and `editlink`. To locate element by 2 class names you can use CSS Selector or XPath, but not `CLASS_NAME`.
So, you can use one of the following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".innerImageWrapper.editlink").click()
```

or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='innerImageWrapper editlink]").click()
```

Also, `find_elements` returns a **list** of web elements, you can not apply `click()` on it.
You should use `find_element` if you want to click on single element or if you want to click on multiple elements you need to iterate over the list of elements and click each one of them, as following:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".innerImageWrapper.editlink")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```